# my double pointer table isnt entierly returned. my function is suppose to split a string with a charset

Tags: c, pointers, charset

```
char **ft_split(char *str, char *charset)
{
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int len;

    if (condition(str[0], charset) != 1)
        while (condition(str[index], charset) != 1)
            index++;

    while (condition(str[index], charset) == 1)
        index++;

    int tab = nbword(str, charset);
    printf("%d, len\n\n", tab);
    char **tableau = malloc((tab + 1) * sizeof(char));

    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        while (condition(str[index], charset) == 1)
            index++;

        len = wordlen(str, index, charset);
        tableau[i++] = malloc(len + 1 * sizeof(char));
        ft_strSPcpy(tableau[i - 1], str, len - 1, index);
        printf("tableau[%d] = %s\n", i - 1, tableau[i - 1]);
        index += len;
    }

    tableau[i] = 0;

    return tableau;

    free(tableau);
}
```

this is where something blocks.

*before main*

```
tableau[0] =  bodeg
tableau[1] =  c vr
tableau[2] = iment 
tableau[3] = uper

in function main
tableau[0] =  tableau[last] = (null)

 c vr
iment 
uper
```

and this is what i get when executed.

so as you can see, in the main function, the first string is empty?? what happenned ?

i also tried to see after my last while, all strings were good.

thank you

Comment: my string was "la bodega c vraiment super"; and charset = "as"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: `char **tableau = malloc((tab + 1) * sizeof(char));` allocates too few bytes by a factor of 8 (or 4 on x86), you need to allocate a block of memory holding **Pointers**, e.g. `char **tableau = malloc((tab + 1) * sizeof *tableau);`